# how to handle chinese characters in teradata

Tags: unix, teradata, informatica

informatica session getting fail with overflow issue for 100 column in the below record
error record:

```
3535^G1001147692^G748131738^GD-PD-2312-00136-A001^G51^GJP 3rd Party order^G12/25/2023 06:56:13^G20026314^GMegumi Sunaoka^GX^GT^GN^G^G^G1001147692^GN^G^GN^G30^GG^G2^G^GTDS^G^GMBN^G3P        P^G12/25/2023 07:57:09^GC40000^G^G12/25/2023 07:57:09^GService_Dragon^G01/04/2024 01:45:46^GService_Dragon^GN^G^G^GDO^G12/27/2023 15:00:00^G^GN^G^G3PP^G^GSAGAWA^GN^GN^GN^GN^G^GN^GY^        G^G^G165000^G3700005252614^GN^G^G24695060^GDRAGON_JPN^G1^G1^GLEGLA^G1^GY^GJPY^G^G^GY^G19^GJP^GNEW^GP^G15321350^G^G^GCCC4^G0^G^G^G12/25/2023 07:56:17^G0^G0^G^G12/25/2023 07:56:15^G^G        N^GN^G^G12/25/2023 07:56:17^G^G^GDW^GN^G^G35004^G^G^G^G

【保有情報】  証書番号：CERTSG-516268 契約者名：三菱総研ＤＣＳ株式会社 型番：V2PBHBLOS 数量：3  開始日：2022/12/28 満了日：202        3/12/27 【見積情報】  更新元証書番号：CERTSG-516268 契約者名：三菱総研ＤＣＳ株式会社 型番：V2PBHBLOS91 数量：3 更新後開始日：2023/12/28 更新後満了日：2024/12/27

^G^G^GN^GHBD^G^GN^GY^        G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G1571537378^G7400004398905^G^GPP^G^GOMAR^GMegumi_Sunaoka@Dell.com^G^G^GJPY^G142.4100000000000000^G142.4100000000000000^G15000.0000^G0^G^GN^GN^G2^G^G^GJPN^G^G^G        N^GN^G^G^G^G^G^G^GN^G^GN^G^G^GN^GN^GN^G ^G^GNA^G^G^GJPN

Error column data:  
【保有情報】  証書番号：CERTSG-516268 契約者名：三菱総研ＤＣＳ株式会社 型番：V2PBHBLOS 数量：3  開始日：2022/12/28 満了日：202        3/12/27 【見積情報】  更新元証書番号：CERTSG-516268 契約者名：三菱総研ＤＣＳ株式会社 型番：V2PBHBLOS91 数量：3 更新後開始日：2023/12/28 更新後満了日：2024/12/27

for that column existing size is  VARCHAR(260) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC, but error column data is 202 size
```

how can I handle the above error

I used datatype as  VARCHAR(260) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC,
but not working

Comment: i would recommend using  VARCHAR(3900) and try... Unicode data needs double the space in memory.

Comment: The string you show contains 202 characters, but using Unicode, characters can take multiple bytes of storage (especially chinese, japanese or corean). I don't know which internal encoding uses Teradata, but your string takes 385 bytes in UTF-8, 404 bytes in UTF-16 or 808 bytes in UTF-32. Note that UTF-8 represents characters with a varying number of bytes : "a" = 1 byte \x61, "保" = 3 bytes \xe4\xbf\x9d (UTF-16 can also sometimes take 4 bytes instead of 2 bytes per character). You can check on https://www.coderstool.com/unicode-text-converter

Comment: Like said above: use at least 4 times the possible max length. And make sure proper UTF settings are used for connectors, source and target connections.

Comment: What is the actual error code / message? Is the "session character set" using UTF8 or UTF16 encoding or is it improperly defaulted to ASCII?